# Can you use AzureDevops build variables within another variable in an Azure Devops Library Group?

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-pipelines-yaml

I'm trying to construct a variable by inserting values from another variable environment variable, a bit like a template.

Similar to this example from Octopus...

[image: Variable Substitution/Binding]

The `ConnectionString` variable is a template which uses `Server` and `Database` variables.

Above the examples are because Octopus is using different values per environment. In my case I'd like to keep the template as an unprotected variable so I can see it and have the inserted variable protected because it contains sensitive information.

I've tried using macro syntax (`$(Server)`) and runtime expression syntax (`$[Server]`), neither of which seem to replace the values at build time.

Expression syntax `${{Server}}` gives me an error "bad substitution" which implies that there's a good substitution but I'm missing something.

Answer (score 0):

This is not supported. We could not use dynamic password when use a service endpoint. If you want to change the password, you need update the endpoint directly.

Besides service endpoint is independent, should not dependent on  other variable or variable group.

No need to use a protected  `SECRET_REPLACED_AT_BUILD` variable with password to protect it. Password in the service endpoint  is also protected.

You could refer the format of Environment Variables with Credential Provider in our [**official link**](https://github.com/microsoft/artifacts-credprovider#environment-variables).

> **VSS_NUGET_EXTERNAL_FEED_ENDPOINTS:** Json that contains an array of service endpoints, usernames and access tokens to authenticate
> endpoints in nuget.config. Example:
>
> ```
> {"endpointCredentials": [{"endpoint":"http://example.index.json", "username":"optional", "password":"accesstoken"}]}
> ```

Comment: Hi, I think we're talking about different things, maybe some more context would help. My build pipeline sets the VSS_NUGET_EXTERNAL_FEED_ENDPOINTS environment variable and it sets it complete with the correct password. However I want to split the private part of that value from the not sensitive part and then combine them before I set the environment variable. Hope this helps. It's not a nuget question or a nuget credential provider question, it's a pure azure devops question really. Perhaps a more abstract example in my question would have been more appropriate.

Comment: Thanks for your update. This is my pre understanding of your issue:" According to your description NUGET_JSON should be your customized service endpoint. And in that endpoint,  you have `"password": "SECRET_REPLACED_AT_BUILD"` You want replace `SECRET_REPLACED_AT_BUILD` to your actual value of that endpoint." Refer to your latest comment `However I want to split the private part of that value from the not sensitive part and then combine them before I set the environment variable.` why you have to first split and then combine them together.  What was the original purpose of this?

Comment: I'm not sure justifying it changes anything but here we go. Recently the PAT expired so it needed to be updated. The variable in DevOps which contained the JSON was protected. This means I couldn't view and edit the JSON, I had to find or recreate the whole JSON with the new PAT. If I store the PAT in a separate variable to the JSON structure I can change the password or the endpoints independently. Alternatively I could store the whole JSON blob in an unprotected variable but I don't want to do that.

Comment: Hi @BenCr Thanks for your quick response. It's not supported. Unfortunately that's not something we offer today, it's also not offer this alternatively  way to update PAT token. You'll need to resort to manually updating your PATs. `The recommended best practice is to use PATs and setup a secret rotation schedule, which in itself is a recommended security best practice irrespective of the type of credentials.` More details please take a look at comment in our official user voice site: https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/idea/817953/allow-personal-access-tokens-that-do-not-expire.html

Comment: Hi @BenCr  This is not supported. Just checking to see if the information provided was helpful. Do you have any other concern? If not and my reply helped. Appreciate for *marking it as an answer*.

Comment: No, the answer is not related to my question, I'm going to edit the question and remove all reference to Nuget (if I still can) to remove any ambiguity.